# Всплывающая кнопка при наведении на объект Web

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, asp.net-mvc, интернет-магазин

Пишу на asp.net mvc, в оформлении/дизайне слаб. Есть такая задумка, чтобы при наведении на объект(в данном случае изображение), появлялась кнопка.
К примеру я навел на изображение и снизу него появилась кнопка "Добавить в корзину". Пример на фото

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

От чего отталкиваться и как реализовать задумку css js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например (используя `translateY(0 \ NNpx )` ):

```css
/* Общая стилизация для наглядности */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
}

.show a{
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Обертка */
li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100px);
  -o-transform: translateY(100px);
  transform: translateY(100px);
}

/* Наведение */
li:hover .show {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://www.legioner-shop.ru/Pictures/original/kepka_gungnir_thor_steinar.png?max_width=900&max_height=900" alt="">
    </div>
   <div class="show">
     <a href="#">быстрый просмотр</a>
     <a href="#">сохранить</a>
   </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://www.legioner-shop.ru/Pictures/original/kepka_gungnir_thor_steinar.png?max_width=900&max_height=900" alt="">
    </div>
   <div class="show">
     <a href="#">быстрый просмотр</a>
     <a href="#">сохранить</a>
   </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```